# Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll Información adicional: Incorrect syntax near ''

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

*Estoy comenzando con mis clases de programación y no se de estos errores al ejecutarlo me sale esto*

**Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll
Información adicional: Incorrect syntax near ''.**

esto me lo señala en esta linea **grabar.ExecuteNonQuery();**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public byte[] Transformador;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void Obtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog Explorador = new OpenFileDialog();

        string Direccion = "All files |*.*";

        if (Explorador.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)

        {

            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(Explorador.FileName);

            Transformador = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Explorador.FileName);

        }
    }



    private void buttonAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-IOFATK12\SQLEXPRESS;  Initial Catalog=dbInventarios; Integrated Security = true");
        string Guardar = "Insert Into dbo.Expedientes (Expediente) Values (@Expediente)";
        SqlCommand grabar = new SqlCommand(Guardar, conn);
        grabar.Parameters.Add("@Expediente", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = Transformador;

        grabar.Connection.Open();

        grabar.ExecuteNonQuery();

        grabar.Connection.Close();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: en principio no veo nada incorrecto en ese codigo, si realizas un rebuild de la solucion y ejecutas se produce ese mismo mensaje? lo planteo porque quizas antes concatenanbas el valor del parametro en un string, pero lo cambiaste a parametros

Answer (score 1):

He tenido que crearme un proyecto porque no entendía porqué te daba error, incluso creando una base de datos con una tabla similiar y escribiendo y la consulta no encontraba un error, hasta que he copiado tal cual tu consulta SQL en mi proyecto y me ha dado el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que me he puesto a comparar las variables de texto donde almaceno las consultas y no podría dar crédito a lo que veía, los caracteres NO ERAN IGUALES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tienes entre el caracter de apertura de paréntesis '('  y la arroba '@' que por alguna extraña razón se ha colado un caracter llamado "ancho cero". Si se borra ese trozo y se vuelve a teclear se arregla. Te dejo el código que he probado para que puedas comprobar la diferencia:

```
public byte[] Transformador;
private void BtnInsertBbdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Transformador = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);

        if (Transformador != null && Transformador.Length > 0)
        {
            string salida = string.Empty;
            bool guardado = false;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbInventarios;Integrated Security=True");
                string GuardarNoFunciona = "Insert Into dbo.Expedientes (Expediente) Values (@Expediente)";
                string GuardarFunciona = "INSERT INTO dbo.Expedientes (Expediente) VALUES (@Expediente)";
                if (GuardarNoFunciona.ToUpper() != GuardarFunciona.ToUpper())
                {
                    int longiNoFunciona = GuardarNoFunciona.Length;
                    int longiFunciona = GuardarFunciona.Length;

                    StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < longiFunciona; i++)
                    {
                        if (GuardarNoFunciona.ToUpper()[i] != GuardarFunciona.ToUpper()[i])
                        {
                            strBld.AppendLine($"CHAR[{i}] - {GuardarNoFunciona.ToUpper()[i]} / {GuardarFunciona.ToUpper()[i]}");
                        }
                    }
                    string parada = strBld.ToString();
                }
                SqlCommand grabar = new SqlCommand(GuardarNoFunciona, conn);
                grabar.Parameters.Add("@Expediente", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = Transformador;

                salida = grabar.CommandText;

                grabar.Connection.Open();

                grabar.ExecuteNonQuery();

                grabar.Connection.Close();
                guardado = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n" + salida, "Error ejecutando la consulta SQL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            if (guardado) MessageBox.Show("Se ha guardado el fichero en base de datos de forma correcta", "Comando SQL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo ejecutas y lo depuras en la variable "parada" verás que la diferencia de caracteres justo comienza en el caracter @, ási que quítalo, ponlo con el teclado y te funcionará.

Saludos.

Comment: Prueba poniendo un `@` antes del texto de esta forma `string variable = @"Insert Into dbo.Expedientes (Expediente) Values (@Expediente)";`

Comment: Hola Andres, no es eso, es que en SU consulta donde pone (@Expediente) entre el caracter ( y la @ existe otro caracter llamado "ancho cero" que es INVISIBLE, y es precisamente este el que está generando el error, prueba a copiar y pegar su consulta en un block de notas y cuenta los caracteres y verás que sale uno de más.

Comment: Me ha costado pero lo he encontrado, es el caracter Alt+65279 (FEFF), pero para que os salga no vale en cualquier editor de texto, algunos lo transforman al caracter espacio normal, como Visual Studio, funcona por ejemplo en Word.

Comment: Ahhh ok, excelente que lo hayas podido resolver... ese tipo de error son los que mas dolor de cabeza nos da a los devs

Comment: Hola tengo la misma problematica, pero como puedo revisar si me sucedio lo mismo con los arrobas

Comment: Realmente el problema no es con las arrobas sino con el carácter de "ancho cero" que es el carácter Alt+65279 (FEFF), ese es el que tienes que buscar, puedes arreglarlo llevándotelo a un editor de texto plano, al pegarlo pierde ese carácter, y cuando lo vuelvas a copiar y pegar se quedará el texto limpio.